# What else can be done for better security against keylogging softwares?

Tags: keyloggers, protection

I've been hearing about keyloggers for the past two years, but never took them seriously. Now, as I've started net banking and managing social networking accounts, I'm very much concerned about safety.

After doing a bit of research, I came across these solutions:

1. Install good antivirus software.
2. In addition to an antivirus, use other malware detectors such Malwarebytes Anti-malware and Hitman-pro, as a single program might not be able to remove all malware.
3. Install Key Scrambler.
4. Use an on-screen keyboard at public places to prevent keylogging from hardware keyloggers.

Still, I don't feel 100% safe as there is always some risk involved, so please suggest **what else can I do for better security** or is what I'm doing enough?

This question is not duplicate as I want to cross-check the security I've taken and also to find out loop holes in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides what you've done already to protect yourself you have a few additional options.

- Use two factor authentication for your accounts.
- Don't use public computers.
- Use a live distro that you know is safe (you can sometimes reboot public machines and usb boot)

Adding these into your routine should make you pretty darned secure.